# how to convert putty known host entry in the registry to Jsch readable known host file

Tags: java, jsch, ssh-keys

I am using jsch library from jcraft.

There is a method `session.setconfig()` and you can

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
```

But I want to add known host file. I am running a windows machine so I exported putty registry to a file and then added the following.

```
config.put("UserKnownHostsFile", "C:\\*****\\KnownHost.txt");
```

but this throws an exception.

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey:
```

So I think the text file might not be properly configured. Can some one point how can I create a list of known hostkeys and how do you add them to Session object.

Also what key value are accepted by Session.setconig()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in JSCH class: setKnownHosts(filename), have you tried that instead of putting it in the config?